# How to make a program with Euclid's algorithm that calculates the gcd , the number of divisions, and the number of different quotients?

Tags: python-3.x

I’m a beginner in Python.
I’m trying to make a program with the Euclid’s Algorithm.
The thing is that I don’t know how to make this program:
The program is inspired by the following observation. The number of lines of the form a = b * q + r produced by the Euclidean algorithm to calculate the GCD (a, b) does not follow a predictable pattern.
 We are going to say that an execution of the algorithm is more interesting than another if the GCD calculated is greater than 1, requires a greater number of divisions and intermediate quotients produced are highly variable.
For example, in calculating the gcd (13, 8) is obtained:

```
  13 = 8 * 1 + 5
  8 = 5 * 1 + 3
  5 = 3 * 1 + 2
  3 = 2 * 1 + 1
  2 = 1 * 2 + 0
  gcd (13, 8) = 1
  5 Steps required
 There are only 2 different quotients: 1 and 2
 It is not a very interesting example.
 Instead, calculating the MCD (455, 355):
 455 = 355 * 1 + 100
 355 = 100 * 3 + 55
 100 = 55 * 1 + 45
 55 = 45 * 1 + 10
 45 = 10 * 4 + 5
 10 = 5 * 2 + 0
 gcd (455, 355) = 5
 6 steps (or lines or divisions) are required
 4 different quotients: 1, 3, 4, 2
 So, this case is more interesting than the last.
```

I want to find interesting cases in a region of natural numbers given by the user. To do this, the program will ask the value of the minimum range of the region, which should be > = 2, the value of the maximum range of the region, which must be > = 3, the minimum value of the GCD that is desired, also the minimum desired number of divisions and the minimum number of different quotients.
So In summary I want to write a program that implements a function ngcd (a, b) that calculates the greatest common divisor of a and b by the Euclidean algorithm. Additionally, this function calculates the other measures during execution. Specifically, the function calculates the gcd of a and b, the number of divisions (lines of the form a = b * q + r) and the number of different quotients generated during the call.

An example of what I’m trying to do is these one:

```
  Enter the minimum value range >=2:  100
  Enter the maximum value range >=3:  200
  Enter the minimum value of GCD: 3
  Enter the minimum number of divisions: 5
  Enter minimum number of different quotients: 4
  GCD (156, 129) = 3, divisions: 5, different quotients: 4   
  GCD (159, 126) = 3, divisions: 5, different quotients: 4
  GCD (171, 141) = 3, divisions: 5, different quotients: 4
  GCD (177, 135) = 3, divisions: 5, different quotients: 4
  GCD (177, 144) = 3, divisions: 5, different quotients: 4
  GCD ( 183 , 126 ) = 3 , divisions: 5 , different quotients: 4
  GCD ( 183 , 135 ) = 3 , divisions: 5 , different quotients: 4
  GCD ( 183 , 141 ) = 3 , divisions: 5 , different quotients: 4
  GCD ( 183 , 144 ) = 3 , divisions: 5 different quotients: 4
  GCD (183, 156 ) = 3 , divisions: 5 different quotients: 4
  GCD (186, 129 ) = 3 , divisions: 5 , different quotients: 4
  GCD (189, 150) = 3, divisions: 5 different quotients: 4
  GCD (192, 141) = 3, divisions: 5, different quotients: 4
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are allowed to use the built-in `from fractions import gcd` if you are it should be really simple [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0x6n.png)

there is two ways to do it, recursively and iteratively, usually recursive functions are cleaner and have better performance, therefore you can implement as this:

Recursive:

```
def gcd(u, v):
return gcd(v, u % v) if v else abs(u)
```

it should give you the idea on the math part at least.